# How to make subscription session with prefilled removable promotion code or discount

Tags: stripe-payments

I've managed to create a checkout page with promotion code like this

```
  const sessionParams: Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams = {
    customer_email: user.email,
    mode: 'subscription',
    line_items: [
      {
        price: process.env.STRIPE_PRICE_CODE,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    metadata: {
      userId: user.userId,
    },
    // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
    // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
    // is redirected to the success page.
    success_url: `${origin}/account/download-app?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${origin}/account/plan-preview`,
  };

  if (req.query.coupon === 'special-access') {
    sessionParams.allow_promotion_codes = true;
  } else {
    sessionParams.discounts = [{ promotion_code: '***' }];
  }

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(sessionParams);
```

But I've noticed that user can't remove the promo code and add his custom code.
[image]

I see other companies checkouts that they do have prefilled promo code with an X to remove it and add their own
[image]

I've tried using discount object with allow_promotion_codes: true, but it seems not allowed by the API.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout does **not** currently support *pre-filling* a promotion code that can be removed by the customer on the payment page. Equally, you cannot pass both the `allow_promotions_code` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-allow_promotion_codes) and pre-fill a promotion code via the `discounts` [hash](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts). The API will error (as you've discovered). In order for the promotion code to be removable by your customer, you will need to only use the `allow_promotion_codes` boolean.

Payment Links **do** support pre-filling of promotion codes via the [URL parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-parameters) (e.g. `https://buy.stripe.com/foo?prefilled_promo_code=bar`), which is likely what you're referencing.

Comment: I suspect via a Payment Link, using the `prefilled_promo_code` URL parameter I referenced above.